# USB tethering for my mobile with PC?

Tags: usb

I am using Wi-Fi connection for my android device. It is signal is very week and most of the time i am fed up with internet connection not available.

But i have a PC in my hand with which is in LAN connection.. Is there any way to use this internet connection my mobile using USB cable?

Just curious to know that this will solve my problem. If yes, please give me in detail.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. Whether you want to use mobile connection in PC or PC LAN connection to mobile?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an Android phone. You may be able to get help on [android.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PC LAN connection to Mobile is not at all possible. But, you can use the mobile connection in PC using USB tethering.

Comment: USB Tethering (sharing internet from PC to Mobile) is possible by using using Reverse USB Tethering tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  Look for "USB Reverse Tethering" in the google play store.  It is not easy but it is possible.

There also another way to do this, with "Virtual WiFi Router", they use the of your computer as hotspot.  But take care when you install it, always refuse all the program they try to install on your computer.  It is possible to install without adware program.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It is the ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) setup guide for Windows 7 on Microsoft's website: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-...